# Shopify discount rules

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-template

I currently have an automatic discount rule setup on my shopify store, however its not working quite how I'd like it. The rule uses amount off discount and essentially you need to add 3 items from an "outfit" collection I have created to have the discount added.

So the idea is you add a set of joggers, a T shirt and a hat to your cart for the discount and it adds 10% discount. Which works perfectly. The problem I have is there is nothing stopping someone adding 2 hats and a t shirt and still getting the discount.

I'm trying to avoid adding an app in to manage this.

Thanks in advance!

I've tried multiple different discount rules to get around this problem, I also tried adding the products into individual collections, so T shirts have their own collection etc.

Comment: It sounds like its working exactly the way you set it up.  Why should selecting 2 hats disqualify from the discount?  Are you thinking more of 'Minimum purchase amount' rather than 'Minimum quantity of items'?  Be clear with what you want.